# How to connect to Db2 from .NET 7

Tags: c#, db2

I'll need to connect to a Db2 server with C#.

On Nuget I've found IBM.Data.DB2.Core V3.1.0.600.

This package seems to be what I'm looking for but I don't get it work. Whenever I try to open the connection I'm getting an error.

```
DB2ConnectionStringBuilder sb = new DB2ConnectionStringBuilder
{
    UserID = "MK1",
    Password = "XXXX",
    Server = "rei5",
    Database = "testrei5"
};

DB2Connection connection = new DB2Connection(sb.ConnectionString);

connection.Open();
```

The error message is:

```
IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Exception (0x80004005): ERROR [08001] 
[IBM] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. 
Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  
Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  
Location where the error was detected: "172.17.1.50".  
Communication function detecting the error: "connect".  
Protocol specific error code(s): "10061", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001
```

According to the official [docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2woc?topic=programmatically-net), I've run these commands in the bin folder from nuget.

```
db2cli writecfg add -database BLUDB -host hostname -port 50000
db2cli writecfg add -dsn alias -database BLUDB -host hostname -port 50000
```

I've set alias to `testrei5` and hostname to `rei5`. This worked after I've renamed the `db2dsdriver.cfg.sample` file in the cfg directory to `db2dsdriver.cfg`.

However, my connection still doesn't open.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you are connecting to Db2-on-cloud, you also need to specify Security=SSL as a parameter for the database and for the dsn in the db2dsdriver.cfg.     After making that change, you should first run the `db2cli validate -connect -dsn XXX -user YYY -passwd ZZZ` to ensure that the db2cli can connect successfully to the target database with whatever credentials you specify. If db2cli cannot connect, then  .net cannot connect.

Comment: I'm not using a cloud variant. It's hosted internally. I've noticed that I'll need to switch from ClientUserID  to UserID. Now I get the error message: IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Exception (0x80004005): ERROR [08001] [IBM] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "172.17.1.50".  Communication function detecting the error: "connect".  Protocol specific error code(s): "10061", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001

Comment: As mentioned, until and unless you get the `db2cli validate -connect ...` working, then your app won't connect. For each new symptom, lookup the code online in the free Db2 knowledge centre for YOUR version of Db2-server. Verify that no firewall or software-router (e.g. windows firewall) is blocking traffic on the specified port number, add a firewall rule if necessary for that port, and verify the port-number is correct and that the target database-instance is up and listening on that port.

Comment: Did you really define a different port on the db2? (50000), it usually should be 446.